# App crashing after touching email text MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm implement`MFMailComposeViewController` in my demp app. However, for some reasons, my app crashes after I touch to add texts in the email text field. But sending WITHOUT adding any text works fine.

My Xcode is not showing too much. Here is what I'm getting:

[image]

I'm setting an initial text already in the email text field. Maybe the issue is here? request any code and I'll be happy to include it.

**UPDATE:**
Here 2 methods where the first method `openMail` fires up when touching the `UIButton`

```
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {

    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailer setSubject:@"Feedback from Demo App user"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myEMAIL@hotmail.com", @"myEMAIL2@gmail.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        NSString *emailBody = @"Happy to hear your feedback!";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

        [mailer release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you create mail controller and set text message

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using ARC, and you're not have strong pointer to your `MFMailComposeViewController`and after display, ARC is releasing it.

use

```
@property (nonatomic,stron) MFMailComposeViewController *mail;
```

and when you're initialize MFMailComposeViewController:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
self.mail = mailer;
```

Comment: Actually I'm not using ARC here. However, I've tried your suggestion and still the app crashes when touching to add a email title or text email. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just do self.mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; and release it in dealloc, not after presentModally.

Comment: Still not working. I forgot to mention that it works fine with the simulator. But not on a read device.

Comment: Can you debug it? Please insert exception breakpoint and tell us there is a problem, did you try to analyze your code by xcode?

Comment: will check tomorrow when I'm home. Really appreciate your help mientus.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to the 'analyze' feature. I never known it before. Now it makes sense how devs detects their memory leaks. I have many leaks fired up. I'll be fixing it and see if my problem was caused due to this. Aaah! obj-c is becoming more exciting . Will report back when I'm done.

Comment: I fixed all leaks now. I noticed something, when my app is offline I face no problem with the in-app email. But when the app is online the app crashes when touching the text field section. By the way, I'm using Reachability native class. I've removed it to check if it was causing the issue but it isn't. I know I'm not clearing things out here.

Comment: Another interesting observation is even if the app running on the background and you turn the wifi on the app crashes directly when touching any textfields of the in app email.  If you would like me to send you the .m code to check it I would be glad to do so. I really appreciate your effort and help.

Comment: http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/ - here you have example for this

Comment: I have copied the code and it never worked. Not even on other ViewControllers. As I mentioned, if the `WIFI` is off the in-app email works just fine. I'd love to share the whole code here but it's too long to be posted here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have this line in your code:

```
[mailer release];
```

If so that is the problem. If not, then PLEASE update our code sample so its exactly what you are using now.